# How come success function is never called in $http.jsonp (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ngTable to display to dynamically the data from a json file and update the table. However, my code is not working.
Here is some snippet of the code:

```
$http.jsonp("http://127.0.0.1:3000/sampledate.json")
        .success(function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $scope.user = data; });
```

Here is the sample of the html table (ngTable):

```
<div ng-controller="tableController">
        <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped" infinite-scroll-distance="3">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                <td data-title="'Id'" sortable="'id'">
                    {{user.id}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'File Name'" sortable="'file_name'" filter="{ 'file_name': 'text' }">
                    {{user.file_name}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Type'" sortable="'type'" filter="{ 'type': 'text' }">
                    {{user.type}}
                </td>    
                <td data-title="'File Date'" sortable="'file_date'" filter="{ 'file_date': 'text' }">
                    {{user.file_date}}
                </td>    
                <td data-title="'Hour'" sortable="'hour'" " filter="{ hour: 'number'}">
                    {{user.hour}}
                </td>    
                <td data-title="'Bucket'" sortable="'bucket'">
                    {{user.bucket}}
                </td> </tr></table></div>
```

Can people give me some ideas of how to troubleshoot this? 
Or give me some ideas about doing my task.

My problem is not a network problem. See below.

Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:3000/sampledate.json
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: Can't use `jsonp` request on a static json file. Also for `$http.jsonp` you must use the callback string outlined in the docs with no variations. You haven't provided any callback param. Since request is to api you control I doubt you want jsonp anyway. Is this a cross port/cross domain request?

Comment: Yes. before it was a cross domain problem. Now, since I use $http.jsonp, it should not be that problem anymore. I used $http.get and that was when there was a cross domain problem.

Comment: Implement CORS on server. Or to use jsonp you would need a server script to pull contents from file and wrap it in the jsonp callback function and you need to add `callback` parameter to the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an error function and see the error the system is throwing.

```
$http.jsonp("http://127.0.0.1:3000/sampledate.json").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //console.log(data);
    $scope.user = data; 
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.error = true;
    //Here, the console.log that you want (with status, headers... your choice)
    console.log(status)
});
```

But I think your problem is about the variables of your code, and not the petition.

Comment: read the jsonp docs will see that you are missing important parts such as callback query param. Also note that `success` and `error` are deprecated in the me docs

Comment: Jsonp now seems to work. Dont know why it didnt... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is wrong:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
```

in that case you would need to use `$scope.data = data;` instead of `$scope.user = data;`

Also, `$data` in the `tr` should then be `data`.

Better call it `$scope.users = data`, so you end up with `ng-repeat="user in users"`

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve what looks like a single user from your `jsonp` call, then you store it into `$scope.user`, but in the html you call a repeat on `$data`.

If your goal is to get multiple users from your call, and then loop through them you have to change 2 things :

First, put the result into a value in your $scope:

```
$scope.users = data;
```

Then loop through it in the html by changing your tag:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
```

This should now work, because it will loop through `$scope.users` that you set after your `jsonp` call correctly.